# Is there a word or name to call someone that gets called a name, yet uses the same name to call others?

Tags: single-word-requests, meaning, phrase-requests

Example, Jim calls Bob a alcoholic, because he is one, Bob drinks alcohol every day and excessively. Bob then starts calling Jim a alcoholic too, even though Jim has never touched a drink in his life.

What is a word/name/phrase that sums up someone like Bob?

Comment: Please show us how to use this word in a sen­tence. Please show your prior re­search, in­clud­ing search­ing this site for in­nu­mer­able du­pli­cates. What reg­is­ter are you talk­ing here, a for­mal word or phrase one might use in a writ­ten con­text or in­stead one more suited to ca­sual con­ver­sa­tion? Are you look­ing for slang or id­ioms? What’s so wrong with *hyp­ocrite* or *hyp­o­crit­i­cal* that we need a whole new ques­tion amidst a vast sea of nearly iden­ti­cal re­quests that have long ago yielded up an­swers like those two I’ve just now men­tioned?

Answer (score 3):

> Is there a word or name to call someone that gets called a name, yet
>   uses the same name to call others?

I'm not certain there is a word to describe a person, but to describe the act:

[projection](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/projection)

meaning 6b.

> : the attribution of one's own ideas, feelings, or attitudes to other
>   people or to objects especially
>
> : the externalization of blame, guilt, or responsibility as a defense
>   against anxiety

Or the Urban dictionary has these definitions:

[Projection](https://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=Projection) (Psychological)

> 1) An unconscious self-defence mechanism characterised by a person
>   unconsciously attributing their own issues onto someone or something
>   else as a form of delusion and denial.
>
> 2) A way to blame others for your own negative thoughts by repressing
>   them and then attributing them to someone else. Due to the sorrowful
>   nature of delusion and denial it is very difficult for the target to
>   be able to clarify the reality of the situation.
>
> 3) A way to transfer guilt for your own thoughts, emotions and actions
>   onto another as a way of not admitting your guilt to yourself.

- This is a noun that can equally serve as a verb. "is he projecting again", "he just projected the whole thing on me as usual", "he just projects it all on everyone else" etc..

Answer (score 0):

A **narcissist** is an archetypical example of such a person. I'm not sure if every instance of projection is necessarily evidence of narcissism, though.

See https://www.learning-mind.com/what-is-psychological-projection/
and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Narcissism#Traits_and_signs